# Using login username for jprofiler floating licencing?

Tags: licensing, jprofiler

We're running jprofiler (version 9) using floating licenses (ejtserver).

Currently each developer has to configure the licence server connection with the licence username.

Is there a way preconfiguring jprofiler to use a specific license server with the system login username as licence username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the arguments

```
-Vjprofiler.licenseKey=FLOAT:[server name or IP address] -Vjprofiler.licenseName=[user name]
```

to the installer to configure the floating license server during an unattended installation.

If you are not running an installer, you can copy the file `$HOME/.jprofiler9/config.xml` or `%USERPROFILE%\.jprofiler9\config.xml` after you have configured JProfiler and copy it to `$JPROFILER_HOME/config/config_template.xml`. Then any new user who starts the JProfiler executable starts with this configuration.

As of 9.2 this it is not possible to automatically use the login name. In 10.0 you will be able to leave the user name empty and the login name will be used.

Comment: Nice to know. Is there already a release date for 10.0?
Till then I'll use a logon script, setting the name property.

Comment: The release will be in Q1/2017